# Proving that a holomorphic $f$ such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow0}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=\infty$ has a zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H(C\backslash\{0\})$ a function such that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow0}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=\infty.$$

Prove that $f$ have some zero in $C\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: Have you considered $1/f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $g = 1/f$. Then $g$ has zeroes at $\infty$ and at $0$.  Suppose $f$ is zero-free on $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$.   Then $g$ is entire.  Also, $g$ is bounded since it has a zero at $\infty$.  Therefore $g$ is constant.  Either $g = 0$ or we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

As a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$, $f$ has the same number of poles and zeroes (counted with multiplicity). Since $f$ has poles at $0$ and $\infty$, it must have at least two zeroes.